# A hello-type message appeared in WebSocket History while using Burp suitea

Tags: burp

While I was developing myself in Bwapp, messages with the hello type in the server-client section of push.services.mozilla in the WebSocketHistory section sent each other. What is the reason for this?

[image: screenshot]

I don't understand that why it happened.